# AKS error when trying to install a private marketplace app

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have created an app that is in a private store on Azure.  I am trying to install the app from the marketplace when I get the following error:

```
Error: [ InnerError: [Helm installation failed : Unable to build the Kubernetes resources in the extension based on the cluster : InnerError [unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: failed to check CRD: failed to list CRDs: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ext-installer-ssdeploy1" cannot list resource "customresourcedefinitions" in API group "apiextensions.k8s.io" at the cluster scope]]] occurred while doing the operation : [Patch] on the config, For general troubleshooting visit: https://aka.ms/k8s-extensions-TSG
```

Here are the role and role binding yamls I tried but that did not work.  I am new to K8s so there are things I do not understand about it.

**role.yaml**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apiextensions.k8s.io"] 
  resources: ["customresourcedefinitions"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

**role-binding.yaml**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ext-installer-ssdeploy1
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role 
  name: ext-installer-ssdeploy1
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ext-installer-ssdeploy1 cannot list resource "customresourcedefinitions at cluster scope" This needs ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding to start with instead of Role and RoleBinding.

Comment: Are you referring to **Azure Private Marketplace** or different external marketplace?

Comment: Shouldn't the name be ext-installer-ssdeploy1 instead of defaults under subjects of role binding yaml?

Something like this-

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ext-installer-role-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ext-installer-ssdeploy1
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: ext-installer-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

Comment: also, what is the output for kubectl get roles,rolebindings --namespace=default
kubectl auth can-i list customresourcedefinitions --as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ext-installer-ssdeploy1 saying?

Comment: @Arko  the output gave me a long list of errors and I can't post them here.  But this is one of the errors:  Error from server (Forbidden): roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubectl" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ext-installer-ssdeploy1" cannot get resource "roles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" in the namespace "default"

Comment: @VenkatV  Yes,  I am referring to the Azure Private Marketplace.

Comment: The error message indicates that the service account ext-installer-ssdeploy1 in the kube-system namespace does not have the necessary permissions to list custom resource definitions in the apiextensions.k8s.io API group.
To resolve this issue, you need to grant the necessary RBAC permissions to the service account.

Comment: OK,  Thanks.  I got past that error.

Comment: Great. I am posting our discussion as an answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicates that the service account `ext-installer-ssdeploy1` does not have necessary permissions to list custom resource definitions in the apiextensions.k8s.io API group. To fix this issue, you need to grant the necessary RBAC permissions to the service account. Also modify the name attribute in your role.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ext-installer-ssdeploy1
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apiextensions.k8s.io"] 
  resources: ["customresourcedefinitions"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create"]
```

```
kubectl apply -f role.yaml
```

After granting the necessary permissions, attempt to install the Helm chart again, it should work.

Reference Doc-
[Official K8s Role Example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)